# Is an empty variable has same size as filled variable in C#

Tags: c#, class, variables, memory

This is fundamental question, I need to suppress memory use of my code in C#. I wonder if I initiate class A (let's say it have 10 variables) and I fill all variables with values. In another case I initiate class A and I fill only 2 variables with values, and let the rest is null or empty if it's a string. Will the first case has the higher memory consumptioon?

Comment: The instance of class A will have the same size. The overall program memory consumption will be higher in the first case because the instance of class A will point to more data allocated in other places (provided A has fields of reference types), or will be the same (if A only has fields of value types).

Answer (score 1):

Probably. If a property of your class is a reference type, then if you assign to this property you will have some memory assigned **because of** that property.
Example:

```
class House{
   object TV {get; set;}
}
```

If you do `var house= new House();` you will use the space of `house` reference and `Tv` reference. 
However if you do this:

```
var house= new House() {
    TV= new {height= 100, width=1000}
};
```

it will take more since now the TV **object** takes space in addition to the TV **reference**. So you will have used extra space for `height` and `width`.

If you have a simple value type as a property:

```
class House{
       int Price {get; set;}
    }
```

It will not make any difference with

```
var house = new House();
```

or

```
var house = new House(){ Price=20000 };
```

That is because `Price` **will be set** to the `int` default value( which is `0`), and every `int` takes the same space regardless of its value.

Comment: You're oversimplifying.  `height` and `width` are almost certainly non-nullable value types, which means they take up the same space whether they are assigned or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, in the first case, if `TV` is a null reference, there is no additional object (just the size of a reference). But when `TV` is an instance of the anonymous type, `new {height= 100, width=1000}`, that object takes up some space. Anonymous types are reference types. An instance of a reference type takes up some space, in addition to the reference itself. So Kristjan Kica is right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an empty variable has same size as filled variable in C# if variable is a value type or a reference: it takes the same memory space.

For example an `int` takes 4 bytes and `long` takes 8 bytes.

It the same for references, assigned or not.

A reference on x32 takes 4 bytes but in x64 it takes 8 bytes.

Each value type takes the size of the value with added the size of the hidden hidden pointer (the hidden reference).

When it is not the same size is for all types based on arrays like `value[]` and strings: in this case the initial size is the pointer size and then the space grows as the data is populated.

Hence the memory size of an array of int grows as you add integers, and it is the same as a string grows.

It is because it is sometimes preferable to use a StringBuilder instead of a String, and to avoid the use of ToList() for example when useless.

To this must be added the references of the methods and the virtual tables.

You can get the size of a serializable instance, excluding the reference and the methods tables, using:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

static public long SizeOf(object obj)
{
  if ( obj == null ) return 0;
  try
  {
    using ( MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream() )
    {
      new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, obj);
      return stream.Length;
    }
  }
  catch 
  { 
    return -1; 
  }
}
```

Comment: A null reference has the same "width" as a reference to something, so that is correct. But in the latter case, the instance being referenced takes up some place in itself. For example `new MyClass { Str = null, }` takes up the same space as `new MyClass { Str = "Mary had a little lamb, Little lamb, little lamb, Mary had a little lamb Whose fleece was white as snow.", }`, but in the latter case there is an additional object, the string instance, which takes up some space. (It could be string interned, of course.)